# How to concatenate string in room dao query?

Tags: android, android-room, android-architecture-components

I'm using a LIKE operator in my Query

```
 @Query("SELECT * FROM item where barcodes LIKE :barcode")
 List<Item> getItemWithBarcode(String barcode);
```

Is there any way that i can append something(**`appendedTxt`**) to the bar code? Like this

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM item where barcodes LIKE (:barcode + 'appendedTxt')")
List<Item> getItemWithBarcode(String barcode);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The || operator is "concatenate" - it joins together the two strings of its operands. [Docs](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html)

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM item where barcodes LIKE (:barcode || 'appendedTxt')")

List<Item> getItemWithBarcode(String barcode);
```

edit: changed double quotes to single